# How to write a string with mutiple lines into file with python

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

```
for j in search(query, tld="co.in", num=10, stop=10, pause=5):
    print(j)
f.writelines(j)
```

i have been trying write J to a text file but it only gives me the 10th url and omits the first nine this is the first time Ive ever been truly stumped can anyone help? for context im using python to search and log google searches and it outputs like
url1 \n
url2 \n
url3 \n
url4 \n
url5 \n
url6 \n
url7 \n
url8 \n
url9 \n
url10
and thats fine but when i try to write it to a file it only writes url 10

Comment: (1) Fix the indentation of shown code. (2) How do you output the right urls? Is there an additional `print`?

Comment: Yes, sorry about that the indentation was a print statement. The url's are just outputted line by line by that search function so that's how they are given to me but when I file write it only does one line.

Comment: The last line must be be in the loop, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The screaming issue here is that f.writelines(j) is outside the loop (If that wasn't just a typo on the post, of course). Also, I see no point in using writelines when you're passing a single string.

```
for j in search(query, tld="co.in", num=10, stop=10, pause=5):
    print(j)
    f.write(j + '\n')
```

Does this make any difference?

Comment: Thank you Luiz! That worked great although im still confused on why it can print one line still outside of the loop but not all of them that doesn't make since to me yet but im still very much learning.

Comment: Ah, For loops usually have what's know as a loop variable, in this case it's **j**. Each time the loop iterates **j** will take on a new value so you only have one iteration to deal with it before it takes on a new value. In your case, each time the loop ran, **j** took the form of a different url. Loop variables only last the lifetime of the loop so they shouldn't be used outside it. You can learn more about them here: [Python ForLoops](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop)